# How to make an asynchronous response a synchronous response (Java: Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I'm quite new to using android studio. My question is, how do i change an asynchronous response into a synchronous response. I am currently using the volleyball library to return data from my database in JSON format.

The problem that I am experiencing is, representing that data into a graph format. You see, due to the structure of my code, the compiler waits for the response (essentially the data that is being sent from my database to android studio) but as its waiting, the compiler moves on to the other parts of the code which involves creating a graph and representing the data from my database into the graph.

But the graph is empty because it has not been fed any data, as we'r waiting for a response.

Here is the code:

```
 private void sendRequest() {
        System.out.println("Triggering send Request");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        showJSON(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(BillReport.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        System.out.println("Send Request done");
    }
```

The send request method is called before the implementation of the graph in the main method.

Bottom line is, I need to figure out how I can get an immediate response as opposed to waiting for a response.

Thank you for taking your time to read this post!

Comment: Put your "implementation of the graph" code in `showJSON()`, so that it is executed when you have your data.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks! The only issue I have with doing it that way is that it would look really messy. I  was looking more towards keeping the thread running a bit longer, long enough to retrieve the response.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait for the response to show the values in the graph. You can cache the data in volley and use it if the server data is not expected to change. You can have a progress bar that will rotate while the data is being retrieved. This is the standard practice.